# 'execfile' is not defined

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS system.
I have tried the following command in terminal to install robotframework-excellibrary

pip install robotframework-excellibrary

it displays the following error:

```
 Collecting robotframework-excellibrary
  Using cached robotframework-excellibrary-0.0.2.zip (61 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-z8dqb4gc/robotframework-excellibrary_0f1b4318c97a4edda05cda502368d95e/setup.py", line 23, in <module>
          execfile(join(dirname(__file__), 'ExcelLibrary', 'version.py'))
      NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have tried to update python3, pip, setuptools still it is provides the same error.

I want to install the robotframework-excellibrary in my system.

Comment: It seems that the library uses python2, namely **Python 2.7.4 (Newer versions not tested)**. No wonder that upgrading python3 doesn't help